# Winium design pattern

Tags: c#, winium

I am using winium C# to test my desktop tool.
I have currently placed all my action methods in one class and just reusing those methods in the tests.
I want to know what design pattern can i use ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same structure as **selenium**. In selenium, mostly **Page Objects** pattern will be followed. Just here we will use forms instead of web pages
For desktop app, 
Create a structure according to your forms.

1.A **Test class** for each form - Write form related tests. (Access your action methods 
  from helper class)

2.A **Helper class** for each form -Write your action methods. (Access your form elements 
  from Form Object class)

3.A **Form Object class** to store all your form elements. (Access Ids,Names of elements from 
  constants file)

4.A **Constants** class for your automation properties like ID and Names. (Store all the Ids 
  and access the paths of application from App.config file)

5.**App config** file -Store Application paths and file paths.

6.A **Data** folder to store files if any.

Hope this helps!